# Fill column with value from database if value in rows match when there are duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

So I have a data frame (D1) and every entry has a code associated with it and these codes are representative of specific categories. In a separate data frame(D2), all the codes have a description. What I need to do is look through D1, match the codes there with those in D2 and pull in the description to an additional column. I've tried to do this using merge, but keep running into duplicate errors. What is the best way to do this?

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'data':['one','two','three','four'],'code':['abc','xyz','abc','lnm']})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'code':['abc','lnm','xyz'],'description':['first','second','third']})

need = 
    data     code     description
0   one      abc      first
1   two      xyz      third
2   three    abc      first
3   four     lmn      second
```

Comment: By default `merge` uses `how="inner"` (which is inner join (obviously)). You might want to try `how="left"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map):

```py
df1["description"] = df1["code"].map(df2.set_index("code")["description"])
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
    data code description
0    one  abc       first
1    two  xyz       third
2  three  abc       first
3   four  def      second
```

Comment: When I try this, it gives me InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @Aliya Does `df2` contain duplicate codes? You can remove duplicates with `df2.drop_duplicates(subset="code")`